# Strange error from Coherence: "A POF Index must be specified for the property..."

Tags: java, caching, oracle-coherence

I'm using the Coherence annotation `@PortableProperty` to annotate cached objects for POF serialization. For example:

```
@Portable
public class Product implements Comparable<Product> {

    @PortableProperty(0)
    private String acronym;

    // other properties and getters/setters ...
}
```

The `pof-config` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pof-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-pof-config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-pof-config
    http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-pof-config/1.2/coherence-pof-config.xsd">

    <user-type-list>
        <!-- include all "standard" Coherence POF user types -->
        <include>coherence-pof-config.xml</include>

        <user-type>
            <type-id>1001</type-id>
            <class-name>
                com.xyz.Product
            </class-name>
        </user-type>

        <!-- More user-type definitions -->

    </user-type-list>
</pof-config>
```

When the server administrator tries to deploy my GAR, he's getting the following error:

`An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
 (Wrapped) (Wrapped: error creating class "com.tangosol.io.pof.ConfigurablePofContext") A POF Index must be specified for the property com.xyz.Product#acronym by specifying within the annotation or enabling autoIndexing on the Portable annotation`

But the `acronym` property *is* annotated with an index (0). I even decompiled the .class file from the GAR to double-check that the annotation is there.

Any ideas what would be causing the error on deployment?

Comment: please share your pof-config.xml

Comment: @ArkadiyVerman, I updated the question with my pof-config

Comment: can't see any issue with your definitions, it looks the same on my program.    the only thing i can suggest is to verify your configuration flags, especially Dtangosol.pof.config.

Answer (score -1):

`acronym` as you have defined it is a field, not a property.

Add a Getter and a Setter, make them public, and put the annotation on the getter.

Comment: It already has a getter and setter. I'll try moving the annotation, but the Coherence documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHDG/api_pof.htm#COHDG5590) states clearly: "@PortableProperty – Marks a member variable or method accessor as a POF serialized attribute."

Comment: This answear is simple not true. You do not need getters/setters for POF serialization. And even if you have them, they will be ignored by serializer if annotation is placed on a field rather than on a getter.